# На пользу ли задавать вопросы, которые кажутся интересными, но в данный момент не актуальны для спрашивающего?

Tags: обсуждение

Например, интересен какой-то вопрос, который в данный момент не актуален. К лучшему ли будет спросить его здесь? Или, если нет необходимости в ответе, то не следует тратить время других участников?

Comment: Лично я в такой ситуации спросил бы. Если он интересен (хотя бы Вам) - это уже повод. Если Вы заинтересовались, то и другие могут заинтересоваться. Насчёт отсутствия необходимости в ответе, я Вас вообще не понял. Если спрашиваете - необходимость есть, как минимум - узнать что-то новое. К тому же, Вы даёте возможность узнать это и другим.

Comment: Приведите пример такого вопроса. Есть подозрение, что такие вопросы будут закрываться с пометкой как "слишком общий".

Comment: @РустамГимранов, например, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1012801/185885

Comment: Я в этих метках не шарю - можете задавать )

Comment: @РустамГимранов, у меня есть пару таких вопросов) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784014/web-api-frames-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922463/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-formdata-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8

Comment: @Дмытрык, ну это нормальные вопросы из такой категории - жрать не просят, но вдруг от нас что-то скрывают )